# I am getting some error when I try to open plank by terminal of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. What can i do to get rid of this error message?

Tags: plank

I am customising my desktop, plank is very beautiful tool and when I am trying to open plank settings by terminal, I get following error message:

```
root@chess-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~# plank
[WARN 15:37:15.984933] [Environment:165] XDG_SESSION_CLASS not set in this environment!
[WARN 15:37:15.984970] [Environment:183] Neither of XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP or DESKTOP_SESSION is set in this environment!
[WARN 15:37:15.985003] [Environment:196] XDG_SESSION_TYPE not set in this environment!
[WARN 15:37:16.254893] [Environment:183] Neither of XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP or DESKTOP_SESSION is set in this environment!
root@chess-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~# plank
[WARN 15:31:53.129888] [Environment:165] XDG_SESSION_CLASS not set in this environment!
[WARN 15:31:53.129925] [Environment:183] Neither of XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP or DESKTOP_SESSION is set in this environment!
[WARN 15:31:53.129956] [Environment:196] XDG_SESSION_TYPE not set in this environment!
[WARN 15:31:53.405971] [Environment:183] Neither of XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP or DESKTOP_SESSION is set in this environment!
```

If anyone knows how can I resolve this, I request them to write please and thank you very much friends. :)

Comment: Plank doesn't need to be run as root. Perhaps you could try a regular user.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/relR8Yl.png This is not opening plank either. I also logged out, logged in, sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, reboot, nothng is happening. May be there is some other way to access plank settings?  Thank you for writing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Plank requires you to use X Window System. On GNOME Wayland is the default window system since GNOME 3.22. This is the [orignal bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1632841). It does not seem that the bug is fixed.

You can try to run GNOME on Xorg server. Check this comment on how to use [gnome-xorg](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1661580#p1661580)

> When you login, after selecting your user just click the gear icon below the password field and select "Gnome on Xorg". Then finish logging in. That selection will be saved and future logins will use is by default.

OR

Edit the file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<user_name>`

Change the line that contains:`XSession=` to:

```
XSession=gnome-xorg
```

Comment: I edited the file but the error is still there. But thanks for writing. :)

Comment: Did you restart your computer after editing the file? GNOME needs to restart after editing the file.

Comment: Yes I restarted. I also did sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, logged off and logged back in and restarted again. I did this twice now. But it is not going away.